# How to use ViewChildren to input images of input tag and display them in console

Tags: angular, image

My HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="linkSubmitForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"></form>
   <input #myInput *ngFor="let link of links.controls; let i=index" class="form-control" type="file" [formControlName]="i" required>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My TS code :

```
@ViewChild('myInput') inputEl: ElementRef;
@ViewChildren('myInput', { read: ElementRef }) many_links_el: QueryList<ElementRef>

get links() { return this.linkSubmitForm.get('links') as FormArray; }

ngOnInit() {  while(--3) this.links.push(this.formBuilder.control('') }

onSubmit() {
let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;

//var formData = new FormData();
this.file = inputEl.files;

console.log('file object', this.file);
this.many_links_el.toArray();

// ???  What to do next? ???
}
```

ViewChild is able to access only first image. I want to input all the images.

So I'm using ViewChildren but can't able to do it...

Comment: can you post code related to `links.controls`

Comment: Have you tried to use only `@ViewChildren` directive without `@ViewChild`?

Comment: I just updated the code @jitender have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop through each element ref in `this.many_links_el` collection something like

```
  let files=[];
    this.many_links_el.forEach((e)=>{
     let inputElement=e.nativeElement;
      if(inputElement.files.length){
         files.push(inputElement.files[0])
      }
    })
    console.log(files)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uynppj)

Comment: @VinayDangwal create an empty array and push files to that array

Comment: @VinayDangwal do you want to create and array of files like `[file1,file2,file3.....]` ?

Comment: yes @jitender. I want to display all the files in one filelist. I can make the array but that won't solve my problem exactly.

Comment: can you tell me how I can apply validators.required .